# Python 2.7 vs 3.8 Lambda for sending logfiles from S3 to Elasticsearch

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda

First off, I'm new to Python with not much experience writing code. I have JSON-encoded logfiles stored in S3, and have built a Lambda function (based on an AWS sample.py) which parses and sends some of these logs into Elasticsearch. It all works well when the Lambda runtime is set to Python 2.7. Here is the code:

```
import boto3
import re
import requests
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth

region = 'us-west-1'
service = 'es'
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, region, service, session_token=credentials.token)

host = 'https://search-siem-hds-sec-zsn57erua5fu5gdkdgnxhj5rsi.us-west-1.es.amazonaws.com'
index = 'index1'
type = 'lambda-type'
url = host + '/' + index + '/' + type

headers = { "Content-Type": "application/json" }

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

time_pattern = re.compile('(202\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\dZ)')
message_pattern = re.compile('(.*)')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:

        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']

        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        body = obj['Body'].read()
        lines = body.splitlines()

            timestamp = time_pattern.search(line).group(1)
            message = message_pattern.search(line).group(1)

            document = { "timestamp": timestamp, "message": message }
            r = requests.post(url, auth=awsauth, json=document, headers=headers)
```

When setting the runtime to Python 3.8, the Lambda fails with message:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

After some reading I added 'b' to the following two lines to try and fix this:

```
######################################################
time_pattern = re.compile(b'(202\d-\d\d-\d\dT\d\d:\d\d:\d\d\.\d\d\dZ)')
message_pattern = re.compile(b'(.*)')
######################################################
```

However this resulted on the following error:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Would any kind Python expert be able to assist or to give me some direction on how to get this working on Python 3.8?

Many thanks,
Sera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file you are reading is not binary, which I presume it is not given that you are comparing its contents with text strings, then change this:

```
body = obj['Body'].read()
```

to this:

```
body = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
```

The `read()` function in Python 3 returns bytes. You want strings.